# How much data is actually in Time Travel?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, time-travel

is it possible to Query Time Travel depth available to a table?

Not the configured retention days, but what is actually stored in Time Travel for a table by a date/time. Ex. a Table is configured for 90 day TT but only has 10 days in TT.
I was thinking about the case of when querying TT and if the data isn't there then we get an error, but is there a way to CHECK, something like a SELECT TT-DATE in a Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS has a column (TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES) to show how much storage is used for time travel:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/table_storage_metrics.html

On the other hand, no historical data shows how much Time Travel data is stored for a table by a date/time.

> I was thinking about the case of when querying TT and if the data isn't there then we get an error, but is there a way to CHECK, something like a SELECT TT-DATE in a Table?

There is a recent behaviour change about time travel:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Time-Travel-Queries-Beyond-Data-Retention-Period-Will-Fail-Pending

This ensures that any query using time travel data will not be able to fetch data beyond the data retention period. *Previously, you were able to query TT data beyond the retention period if the data is not changed.* So if you check the configured retention days (and table creation date), you should not get any error when you query TT data.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Time-Travel-Queries-Beyond-Data-Retention-Period-Will-Fail-Pending